# Is it possible to use ComputerCraft to show the TPS of a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-computercraft

Sometimes a Minecraft server is running a bit slow. How slow? Well, that's what we want to know. With this program, we should be able to see what the currently Ticks Per Second (TPS) is on a nearby monitor. Note that there are usually 20 ticks per second. This would probably be used in an admin room so that operators can see what the current TPS is.

Comment: I imagine it depends on if the Lua is emulated within Minecraft or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in this [Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/mindcrack/comments/1f7vqi/introducing_tickprofiler_a_bit_late_but_better/), there is a program called TickProfiler which is commonly used for Lag-busting. Note that this will not work unless you install the profiler on the server.

According to the creator of this program:

> I've made a small update now which allows it to be used with ComputerCraft to put up a display showing the locations of laggy blocks, entities and chunks.
>
> It's quite easy to set up, just put this [lua file](https://github.com/nallar/TickProfiler/) on a computer, and open TickProfiler's config file, then set it up to write with an interval above 0, and the file location as `world/computer/COMPUTERID/profile.txt`, with `COMPUTERID` replaced with the ID of the computer you're using to display this information.